# Nginx allow access to specific location, and return 444 for all others

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to make it so my default server only allows access to one PHP file for AWS ELB's health check.  I need PHP to serve it so it knows PHP is up/running on the instance.  I am able to do the following to deny access with a 403:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    location /path/elb.php {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/elb.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        allow all;
    }

    deny all;
}
```

However, ideally I want to use `return 444;` instead of `deny all;`.  It appears that using `return 444;` supersedes the location statement above it, as it will not work.  Any suggestions, or is using `deny all;` the best I will get in my scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap `return` into `location`.

```
location / {
    return 444;
}
```

But actually I don't see why you would want this.

Comment: This worked!  Thanks for your suggestion -- I didn't think to wrap the return into location.